# Safe to start a php session on get_header action?

Tags: headers, session

I now usually php sessions are started from the init hook, but get_header runs before writing the page, sono technically speaking, I can open a session from there. Is there any other reason I should not do it?

```
add_action('get_header', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession(){
  if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
  }
}

function myEndSession() {
  //session_destroy ();
}
```

Comment: Why though? What's wrong with `init`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s nothing that requires that `get_header` run before output starts, you could put it in the middle of a template file after other content and still have a perfectly valid theme.

`template_redirect` is the last action where it is guaranteed that no output has started yet.